# Why I cannot use express to create my skeleton folder structure

Tags: node.js, express

So I want to create a new project by using this:
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/Server-side/Express_Nodejs/skeleton_website

Notice that when you install express generator you can create the folder structure by using "express". But I have installed both express and express-generator, but when I try to use "express" command, my shell just keeps showing "bash: express: command not found".

Did I forget to install some npm packages? Please feel free to point me out! Thank you so much!

Comment: `npm install express -g` && `npm install express-generator -g` install express globally

Comment: @Jason White It is not working. + express@4.16.4
updated 3 packages in 26.833s
Jiatongs-MacBook-Pro:nodeauth jiatongli$ express
bash: express: command not found

Comment: Got it! Thank you so much @ Jason